# how to pass id across tabs in mvc razor view

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-ajax

I have an mvc view with multiple bootstrap tabs. Once i clicked on save in the first tab an entry will be generated in the database and an id (identity key in the db) will be generated. When i click on the next tab (i use the jQuery click event) i want to pass the id generated from the first tab.

```
 @model MyProject.ViewModels.MydatabaseMyVM
 <div class="container">   
<div class="row">
    <h2>
        Create Staff</h2>
</div>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
<ul id="datatabs" class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified">
        <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#details" id="TabDetailsLink">Personal
            Details</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#Tab1" id="TabTab1Link">Tab1</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#Tab2" id="TabTab2Link">Tab2</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#Tab3" id="TabTab3Link">Tab3</a></li>
    </ul>

 var data = $form.serialize(); $.post(url, data).done(function () {}.
```

In my first tab i have fields from the student model, there is an id which will get generate from the database. On save of that i want to retain that id and when i click on another tab the id should pass to the action through ajax call.
I am using mvc 4 razor view and Bootstrap tab.
Can someone please guide me on how to pass the id generated at database from one tab to another. EF is used for accessing database

Comment: how are you saving your data on first tab? I mean are you posting a form or are you posting via ajax? Also, what technology are you using on accessing database?

Comment: 1. Ajax call 2.EF for db access .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, on first tab, when you click Save, you post the form using ajax to StaffCreate(), which in terms return a view (not so sure why you are returning a View, but I will assume it is used else where).

Is it not possible when you post to StaffCreate(), you save the staffId in a session.

Then when you click second tab, in your jquery click event, first do a get request to a Action which just return staff Id as Json Result, once you got the id, do what ever you want with it.

So a pseudo code something like:

```
// your current action
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult StaffCreate(MydatabaseMyVMstaffvm)
{
    // previous omitted for simplicity

        Staff objStaff = MyService.StaffCreate(staffvm.Staff);
      
        Session["StaffId"] = objStaff.StaffID;
    // reset omitted for simplicity
}
```

Action for getting the StaffId

```
public ActionResult GetCreatedStaffId()
{
    return Json(Session["StaffId"], JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)
}

// your tab click event
$("").click(function{
    $.getJSON( "@Url.Action("GetCreatedStaffId")", function( data ) {
        // data is your StaffId
    }
})
```

---

## Method 2 Psuedo code Store StaffId in hidden input

in the view which you return in StaffCreate(), do something like

```
<input type="hidden" id="hidStaffId" value="@Model.Staff.StaffID" />
```

your tab click event

```
// your tab click event
$("").click(function{
    var staffId = $("#hidStaffId").val();
})
```

Comment: Is there any way to use with out session variable

Comment: There is possible two one I can think of: 1. when you return the View, create a hidden input which you store the id, then when tab click, use jquery to get value from that hidden input - but this can be flawed since anyone can change the hidden input value. 2. when ajax call to action, instead of reading from session, re-query db with information you have for staff.

Comment: can you show me a sample code to create hidden input

Comment: i m getting null reference exception..the id will not generate when i load the view.

Comment: let me check whether ir exist or not in view

Comment: but i am not loading the view again after save . so how the value is going to bind in hidden field

Comment: by your description in question, you id will be generated and you will be assigning the id to the viewModel, if you are getting null, then your code ` staffvm.Staff.StaffID = objStaff.StaffID` would have throw exception too.

Comment: in your post action StaffCreate(), it is returning a View at the end with the model containing the StaffId you just created

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105390/discussion-between-jubi-and-alan-tsai).

Comment: That return statement is to remains in the screen if there is any model validation error.